# How can I effectively look at images in shell32.dll by simply looking at the raw data and chang how it's rendered?

Tags: bitmaps, shell32.dll

I'm using this website http://rawpixels.net/
to look at the shell32.dll file and I'm trying to find the right settings to use so I can see the icons within the file.

I know that there should be an alpha and I'm assuming it's 8 bits per channel so it would be RGBA32, and i set the iamge width to be 32 pixels but I still don't see any distinguishable images.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish, bigger picture?  Might be easier to use another method.

Comment: I want to be able to distinguish the raw bitmap images within shell32.dll by viewing the raw data as an entire bitmap. Like this https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fGwEIriq1MM

Comment: Do you have to do this using this website? Would another method work?